# Webview Fragment Error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, drop-down-menu, webview

Im trying to implement a webview inside one of my pages but I am using an "else if" for the fragment.  Im getting and error on the line "changeFragment(new CalendarFragment());", saying that it cannot be applied to my Calender Fragment file.  Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.special.ResideMenu.ResideMenu;
import com.special.ResideMenu.ResideMenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MenuActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ResideMenu resideMenu;
    private MenuActivity mContext;
    private ResideMenuItem itemHome;
    private ResideMenuItem itemProfile;
    private ResideMenuItem itemCalendar;
    private ResideMenuItem itemSettings;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContext = this;
        setUpMenu();
        changeFragment(new HomeFragment());
        Parse.initialize(this, "123", "IHecHh");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MenuActivity.class);
    }

    private void setUpMenu() {

        // attach to current activity;
        resideMenu = new ResideMenu(this);
        resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.menu_background);
        resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);
        resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);
        //valid scale factor is between 0.0f and 1.0f. leftmenu'width is 150dip. 
        resideMenu.setScaleValue(0.6f);

        // create menu items;
        itemHome     = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_home,     "Home");
        itemProfile  = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_profile,  "Profile");
        itemCalendar = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_calendar, "Calendar");
        itemSettings = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_settings, "Settings");

        itemHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemSettings.setOnClickListener(this);

        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemHome, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemProfile, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemCalendar, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemSettings, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);

        // You can disable a direction by setting ->
        // resideMenu.setSwipeDirectionDisable(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);

        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_left_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_right_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return resideMenu.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == itemHome){
            changeFragment(new HomeFragment());
        }else if (view == itemProfile){
            changeFragment(new ProfileFragment());
        }else if (view == itemCalendar){
            changeFragment(new CalendarFragment());
        }else if (view == itemSettings){
            changeFragment(new SettingsFragment());
        }

        resideMenu.closeMenu();
    }



    private ResideMenu.OnMenuListener menuListener = new ResideMenu.OnMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void openMenu() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void closeMenu() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){
        resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();
    }

    // What good method is to access resideMenu？
    public ResideMenu getResideMenu(){
        return resideMenu;
    }
}
```

CalendarFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class CalendarFragment extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.xxxx.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return (true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }




        }
```

Comment: please remove your `Parse` account secret key API.

Answer (score 0):

your `CalendarFragment` is not actually a `Fragment` but an `Activity` since you extended Activity

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Activity
```

but the `changeFragment` method takes a parameter a `Fragment`, causing a compile time error,

Comment: I deleted the "changeFragment line completely but it wont open the calender page.  Any ideas?

Comment: You have to declare the activity into the manifest and the start it